# How to properly register/unregister ContentObserver

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-lifecycle, contentobserver

I explain my scenario: I have an app that saves, on its own DB, some "Contact" taken from the device.

Lets say:

1. My app is in the foreground, showing contacts taken from the db
2. User opens the device contacts list and deletes the contact "Mark Smith"
3. User goes back to my app

At the point 3, my app must be aware that something happened, and, possibly, deletes the contact "Mark Smith" from its on DB.

So, to listen to `ContactsContract.Contacts` changes, I used `ContentObserver`.

I read that I should register the `ContentObserver` in `onResume()` and unregister it in `onPause()`; of course, following this rules the `ContentObserver` will not work in my scenario, since when the user open the device contact list, my app will call `onPause()` and will unregister my `ContentObserver`, so when the user comes back to my app, my app won't know something changed on `ContactsContract.Contacts`.

According to your experience, can I register a `ContentObserver` in `onCreate()` and unregister it in `onDestroy()`?
Everywhere I read to manage `ContentObserver` with `onResume()` and `onPause()` to avoid memory leak.

Thank you guys.

Comment: Don't you have more fundamental issues? What if the user changes something in contacts, and your process is not running, because the user hasn't been in your app for an hour? On Android 7.0+, you could use `JobScheduler` and `addTriggerContentUri()` to find out about these changes even when your app is not around, but that is not available for older devices.

Comment: Thank you for your advices man :) but now i just need to solve this issue.
I'll apply other solution when my app is not running

Comment: Well, FWIW, I am not aware of there being a problem with registering a `ContentObserver` in `onCreate()` and unregistering it in `onDestroy()`.

Comment: yes, keep going with `onCreate()` and `onDestroy()` pair

Comment: Thank you guys :)

Comment: @CommonsWare : So what would be the solution ? I am starting a service inside `ContentObserver#onChange()` to handle changes. Also, how to properly unregister the `ContentObserver` ? for example in the case : register `ContentObserver` when user logs-in and unregister it when user logs-out ? there is this `unregisterContentObserver()` method, but it needs the `ContentObserver` object, which is lost after registering (as login and logout events are far apart in time). Right now, I am just disabling the `Service`.

Comment: @ZeekHuge: "So what would be the solution ?" -- I suggest that you ask a separate Stack Overflow question, where you can provide a [mcve] and explain, in detail, exactly what your concerns are.

Comment: @CommonsWare is it better solution to always read contacts in every `onResume` instead of registering `contentObserver` in `onCreate` and unregistering it in `onDestroy` which may results in memory leaks? but i am worried about multi window which may repateadly calls `onResume`

Comment: @WIZARD: You should not get a memory leak by registering a `ContentObserver` in `onCreate()` and unregistering it in `onDestroy()`. Whether your `onResume()` approach is better or not depends a lot on what you are doing overall with these contacts.

Comment: @CommonsWare i am using contacts in a call log but i am worried about multi window which may calls repeatedly `onResume` however i am using back thread to getting contacts info i put every contact info in a catch to get its info one time for all call logs but this catch is useless when i have to clear it in every `onResume`

Comment: @CommonsWare but Android may kill app after `onPause` not calling `onDestroy` is this products memory leak because `contentObserver` has a strong (am i true is it strong?) reference to my object (my content observer class could not be static inner class of activity because it should notify activity) is there a solution to avoid this memory leak?

Comment: @WIZARD: "but Android may kill app after onPause not calling onDestroy is this products memory leak" -- if Android does not call `onDestroy()`, either your entire process is terminated or you crashed with an unhandled exception. If your entire process is terminated, there is no leak, as you do not have any more objects of any type. If you crashed with an unhandled exception, you have bigger problems than a memory leak.

Comment: @CommonsWare There is also another question i think change listeners like `LocalBroadcastManager` do not get any change notify after `onStop` of activity is this true or false? is this also true for contentObservers?

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks "if Android does not call `onDestroy()`, either your entire process is terminated or you crashed with an unhandled exception" is this also true for all Android objects like services and other android objects if `onDestroy` is not called app process is already terminated?

Comment: @WIZARD: When your entire process is terminated, there is no possible memory leak, as you do not have any more objects **of any type**. Neither `LocalBroadcastManager` nor `ContentObserver` is connected to the activity lifecycle. If you have additional concerns in these areas, ask separate Stack Overflow questions, please.